# Inline Regular Expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a character in a string.
This works when I use the RegExp() object to create the regular expression :

```
var str = "a-b-c-d";

var regex = new RegExp('\-','g');

str.replace(regex,'@');
```

So this works and I get "a@b@c@d".

What if I want to use an inline regular expression , say:

```
str.replace("/\-/g",'@')
```

it does not work. How do I do this without using RegExp();

Comment: Please [**read the documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes (**Regex literal not string literal**):

```
str.replace(/\-/g,'@')
```